# How to use the robot library to press: { or }

Tags: java, runtime-error

I Am tring to do a bot that you put instruccions like say: hello

But when I try to use

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BRACELEFT);

or

robot.keyPress(221);

one or the other should press: {

but no it throws me the exception of an invaid key code.
So can anyone tell me how to type: { and }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use shift and the key that is there underneath it. The Robot class doesn't reach all ascii characters. Here is an example:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET);
```